# Pull data from incrementing XML files

Tags: php, html, xml, web

So heres the scenario.

I need to pull data from XML files located on the web (individually this is easy enough), but my problem is that a new file with an incremented filename is added from from time to time.

So for example, one day a filename may be www.website.com/00001.xml and the next day, a new file is added as www.website.com/00002.xml

I need to create a script, ideally in PHP, that will automatically refresh every couple of hours and pull the data from the new XML file, if the xml file is not present yet then it will retry that same number again. Hopefully all this can then just be put into rows in an excel file.

The question is basically, what is the best way to go about this? if anyone could point me to something similar thats already out there, then that would be great.

Thanks in advance

Comment: get 00001.xml, store data AND filename to DB. Get filename from DB, check if filename + 1 exist in folder, if so, repeat.

Comment: Can 000001.xml have changed since you last fetched it?  Or are you saying the existence of 000002.xml means there are updates, plus there could be updates in 0000001.xml too?